# Copying cordova 2.2.0 .jar

Tags: cordova

I need the new .jar file to upgrade to cordova 2.2.0. But where can I find it?

Do I have to generate it and how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can download it from [the phonegap github repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/2.2.0).

You can find the lib in the lib/android/ folder.

To create a new project, you can use the lilb/andoird/bin/create.bat file.

Comment: @luisfer you'll need to pair it with the cordova-2.2.0.js file for Android as well.

Comment: I don't understand why this is necessary.  I was not able to find any documentation about this. Does anyone have insight on why this is necessary?

Comment: Wow, I just realized the bin/create script removes framework/cordova-2.2.0.jar every time you run it.  <sarcasm>That's pretty cool...</sarcasm>

Comment: The cordova download from Apache (http://www.apache.org/dist/incubator/cordova/) doesn't contain the jar file. However the zip download from github does.

Answer (score 3):

As I answered in this question:
[Where is cordova-2.7.0.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637284/where-is-cordova-2-7-0-jar/21199665#21199665)

In order to obtain the cordova.2.x.x.jar file you only have to do the following steps:

1. Download from the Phonegap website the project. For version 2.9.1 follow this link: http://phonegap.com/install/ and navigate to the version your looking for (2.9.1) it will link you to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.1.zip
2. Once downloaded of course you unzipped and navigate to the **framework** directory
3. You will have to choose the version of android you want to use, if you have downloaded the Android SDK and added to the path variable of your system you can do this:

   ```
   android list targets
   ```

   It will give you an answer like this one:

   ```
   Available Android targets:
   ----------
   id: 1 or "android-8"
   Name: Android 2.2
   Type: Platform
   API level: 8
   Revision: 3
   Skins: WQVGA432, QVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
   ABIs : armeabi
   ----------
   id: 2 or "android-17"
   Name: Android 4.2.2
   Type: Platform
   API level: 17
   Revision: 2
   Skins: WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA432, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
   ABIs : armeabi-v7a, x86
   ----------
   id: 3 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
   Name: Google APIs
   Type: Add-On
   Vendor: Google Inc.
   Revision: 3
   Description: Android + Google APIs
   Based on Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
   Libraries:
   * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
     Collection of video effects
   * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
     API for USB Accessories
   * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
     API for Google Maps
   Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
   ABIs : armeabi-v7a
   ----------
   id: 4 or "android-19"
   Name: Android 4.4
   Type: Platform
   API level: 19
   Revision: 1
   Skins: WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA432, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
   ABIs : armeabi-v7a
   ```
4. I choose the last one so I did:

   ```
   android update project -p . -t android-19
   ```
5. And finally

   ```
   ant jar
   ```

   The result is something like:

   ```
   [jar] Building jar: /home/jgonzalezd/Downloads/phonegap-2.9.1/lib/android/framework/cordova-2.9.1.jar

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   Total time: 10 seconds
   ```

Now you've got your jar.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you build a new project it seems to remove cordova-2.2.0.jar from the Phone Gap folder.

You can just copy it back over to run the create script