# The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, cordova

For some reason, after going through Phonegap's non-inclusive instructions (it doesn't even mention setting up ANT, or the headaches with Ant and JDK), this doesn't work at all:

```
package com.HealthTrustSoftware.AndroidTemplate3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class AndroidTemplate3 extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

It gives 5 errors referencing the fact that org.apache.cordova can't be resolved.  I'm entirely sure what to do at this point.  Please help.  This is after 3 hours of trying to get the sdk working and finally being able to open a project within eclipse.  After following the steps on their documentation, I am left with a wasted 3 hours unless I can figure this out.

Comment: Make sure `org.apache.cordova` is on your classpath.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but HOW?

Comment: Are you in a Java Project (as Eclipse considers it)?  Open its Properties and add the necessary libraries to the Build Path.

Comment: Do you see a cordova-2.2.0.jar in your project libs directory?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. Following what was written in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13399662/413785), I finally made it work.

After you download cordova from [phonegap github page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/2.2.0), you will find cordova-2.2.0.jar and cordova-2.2.0.js in lib/android folder. After running "./create ...", copy cordova-2.2.0.jar into your projects libs folder and cordova-2.2.0.js into your www folder. Then import the project into eclipse and it should work.

I had to go to "Project -> Properties -> Android" and select a newer SDK (I selected the latest one available on the list) and than run the "Project -> Clean" as well.

Comment: The "from phonegap github page" is key here.

Comment: Having a very similar problem with cordova-2.7 and the importing jar fix isn't solving it.

Comment: Same issue here with cordova-2.7

Comment: Same issue in phonegap 3.4.0 android

Answer (score 7):

In addition to copying cordova-2.2.0.jar from the phonegapp download to the libs folder of the project I had to manually add it to the projects libraries.

**Procedure:** Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs... Then select the libs from the project itself

Answer (score 3):

Android studio: File -> Invalidate cache / Restart. Worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

I initially got around this using one of the solutions posted above: about downloading the phonegap from github and pasting in the cordova-2.2.0.jar and cordova-2.2.0.js files into the generated directories.

After fiddling around with the path and environment variables these files are already in place (project/libs/cordova-2.2.0.jar and project/assets/www/cordova-2.2.0.js) now for me after running the "create" command on command line.

I am using the ANT that came bundled with Eclipse so my PATH variable includes:

**C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\bin;**

and I added an environment variable for ANT_HOME of:
**C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730**

I tested adding \bin or removing it to both the PATH and environment variable for ANT_HOME and this was the winning combination.

Answer (score 2):

Run `cordova -d build`. If it says anything about "Unable to locate tools.jar", fix that. Then  completely rebuild the application by running `cordova platform rm android`. Also remove the project from eclispe. Then recreate the app by running `cordova platform add android` + `cordova build`. Finally add the project in eclipse again.

`org.apache.cordova` should now be included and everything should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Replace  your header with some miner changes   like bellow

```
 import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 in the getting started guide is the only part specific to phonegap. The rest is setting up a general android development environment. Instead of eclipse classic, get the ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html - that includes a custom version of eclipse with most of the android stuff ready to go.

The default link to cordova-2.2.0.jar worked fine for me, though it did take a bit of effort to work out that if you want to use a custom build of cordova it needs to be set up as an android library dependency in project properties.

Comment: I also need to port to ISO.  The libs folder is co.

Answer (score -1):

Download [apache cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/#download) jar and add it to lib folder and classpath.

Comment: your link just points to the same repo that I already downloaded!

Comment: @AndrewRhyne:If you already downloaded, then have you added it to classpath?

Comment: There are absolutely no instructions on their documentation regarding this.  Can you please point me in the right direction?  I don't see a cordova.jar in the project folder at all

Comment: I need to step out. See this link, it may help. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android