# Config cannot be resolved in java file phonegap error ?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am getting an error in the below java code saying Config cannot be resolved ?

Phone Gap version = phonegap-2.9.1

Cordova2.2.0.jar was added by be in eclipse as external library.

```
Error on the super.loadUrl line: Config cannot be resolved 


package com.cfvabbotsford.bustransit;


import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class CFVAbbyBusTrial extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

       // super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

.Config.xml file(path res/xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>

    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>


    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->

    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add cordova2.2.0 jar into lib folder and also put same jar into www folder.

After putting jar, clean your project.

It is worked for me. for more information follow below link.

[The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615964/the-import-org-apache-cordova-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: same problem, not fixed