# Error in importing cordova existing projects in android using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Installed  and have set path for cordova,jdk and android sdk and when importing the existing projects which has HTML designed file and Javascript file,Its showing an error in activity file.Although I hvnot entered any coding there.

[image: error]

I do understand that there is an error in Cordova library

I tried to import it from **Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Library** and I cannot see any libraries there

I have also tried updating the Cordova.

Plz help ..you can also see the errors in the image above

Comment: have you added cordova jar file?

Comment: But there is no Cordova Jar file in version 3.5 ?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615964/the-import-org-apache-cordova-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Hv tried this and it seems its only for the previous versions and not for version starting from 3.x

Comment: Tried as per the above link and still there is no improvement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating a new cordova project I have opened eclipse and selected File -> New -> Other -> Android Project from Existing Code and opened platforms\android.

-> Then check the project name and uncheck the cordova library and tick-mark the copy projects into Workspace

-> Properties of the project and  Java Build Path -> Source and Add Folder to include the CordovaLib\src folder

->Then Project->clean

and this seems to work fine for me

Comment: If you want to be able to build from the Cordova CLI (as well as Eclipse) DON'T remove the reference to CordovaLib under Properties -> Android in the Library section, even though it's marked with a red X and Project is ?

Answer (score 1):

Still if you dont get Cordovalib file in Java Build Path , just copy the files from

```
CordovaLib -> src
```

copy the folders(i.e com and org) and paste in eclipse `src` folder.

this worked for me