# Reason for getting the error on org.apache.cordova.whitelist package in my command Line Interface(CLI) created Project for platform as Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, smp

I am trying to create a simple cordova project using the command line Interface

After Plugins Release and Moving plugins to npm: April 21, 2015 as on site .

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html

Is is said that core plugins have changed their IDs from org.apache.cordova.* to cordova-plugin-*.

When I am importing the project in which I have added the plugin using android as a platform it is showing the error on the package for plugin like

> org.apache.cordova.whitelist

Can any one please suggest how can the renaming of the packages be done or either the error can be remove from my project or At least how the project can be complied successfully without getting any error on to it.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the error that you're facing? Please edit your question and paste the error with **code** formatting rather than as a quote. Check this answer for successfully adding and calling the whitelist plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29916802/4412363

Comment: See if this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382631/error-in-importing-cordova-existing-projects-in-android-using-eclipse