# Cordova Plugin Compactibility Issues

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on an Cordova Android application, Cordova 1.5, 1.9,2.0 is used in the project. Now I need to add an additional plugin, I downloaded from `github` and created a `package` and added the files to `lib` folder I encountered the following errors:

```
 The import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext cannot be resolved
 The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved
```

Then after googling I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615964/the-import-org-apache-cordova-cannot-be-resolved). 
After downloading and running `create.bat` I copied those files to `cordova2.2.jar` `lib` folder and `cordova2.2.js` to `www` folder.
When running the application I encountered the following erros

```
    Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/AccelListener
    onversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/AccelListener;
```

Then after some googling I came across a post that suggested to uncheck Android Private Libraries from the `Properties->Android build Path`.

I could resolve all errors and build the application but the application is Crashing when launched.
 what is the solution to include the plugin ?