# Where is cordova-2.7.0.jar?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I struggle to build a first Android app from HTML5.

So, I follow [this detailed tutorial](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/ticket-monster/tutorial/HybridUI/)...

It seems that I should add a .jar of Cordova to the project's libs folder, in order to be able to call Cordova's functionnalities in my app.java file. However, I can't find this cordova-2.7.0.jar file anywhere.

Maybe shall I generate it? Therefore I tried an other option, by creating the project from the command line tool following the [official getting started guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), but there's no cordova.jar either in the generated project files.

I feel Cordova is not so easy to handle at first...

(By the way, I'm also looking for a Cordova JS file...)

---

EDIT: To answer to poiuytrez, here is my cordova package, downloaded from http://cordova.apache.org/
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found a solution following the github doc https://github.com/apache/cordova-android#building

First, you need the `commons-codec-1.7.jar` file. It's downloaded to cordova-android using `create` :
Check http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

```
create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>"
```

- `project_folder_path` is the path to your new Cordova Android project
- `package_name` is the package name, e.g. com.YourCompany.YourAppName
- `project_name` is the project name, e.g. YourApp (Must not contain
  spaces)

This process should download `commons-codec-1.7.jar`.

Then, the following step is not explained in the getting started guide: `cordova-2.7.0.jar` has to be generated with an ant command line, after having copied the `commons-codec-1.7.jar` to the framework/lib directory.

```
android update project -p . -t android-17
ant jar
```

And here we go!

Comment: oh god... phonegap is such a mess. I'm trying to install this pile or errors for 3 days now. Your solution isn't clear to me. I created a project via command prompt `create`. Now where exactly should the `commons-codec-1.7.jar` be downloaded to? Where can i find it?

Comment: And when you download phonegap 2.9 they have done away with the Jar file and appear to have all the source in the zip file. as Sumit said ..... what a mess!

Answer (score 13):

In order to obtain the cordova.2.x.x.jar file you only have to do the following steps:

1. Download from the Phonegap website the project. For version 2.9.1 follow this link: http://phonegap.com/install/ and navigate to the version your looking for (2.9.1) it will link you to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.1.zip
2. Once downloaded and unzipped, navigate into the directory `framework` in `phonegap-2.9.1/lib/android/framework`
3. You will have to choose the version of android you want to use it will be your target version of android that phonegap will be compiled for, if you have downloaded the Android SDK and added to the path variable of your system (if you have not look below) you can do this:

   ```
   android list targets
   ```

(If you dont have the SDK in you system path yet, you will need to add two directories **tool** and **platform-tools** that are inside the SDK folder. Try the previos command and...)

```
It will give you an answer like this one:

    Available Android targets:
    ----------
    id: 1 or "android-8"
    Name: Android 2.2
    Type: Platform
    API level: 8
    Revision: 3
    Skins: WQVGA432, QVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
    ABIs : armeabi
    ----------
    id: 2 or "android-17"
    Name: Android 4.2.2
    Type: Platform
    API level: 17
    Revision: 2
    Skins: WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA432, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
    ABIs : armeabi-v7a, x86
    ----------
    id: 3 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
    Name: Google APIs
    Type: Add-On
    Vendor: Google Inc.
    Revision: 3
    Description: Android + Google APIs
    Based on Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
    Libraries:
    * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
      Collection of video effects
    * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
      API for USB Accessories
    * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
      API for Google Maps
    Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
    ABIs : armeabi-v7a
    ----------
    id: 4 or "android-19"
    Name: Android 4.4
    Type: Platform
    API level: 19
    Revision: 1
    Skins: WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA432, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
    ABIs : armeabi-v7a
```

4. I choose the last one so I did:

   ```
   android update project -p . -t android-19
   ```
5. And finally

   ```
   ant jar
   ```

   The result is something like:

   ```
   [jar] Building jar: /home/jgonzalezd/Downloads/phonegap-2.9.1/lib/android/framework/cordova-2.9.1.jar

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   Total time: 10 seconds
   ```

Now you've got your jar.

Comment: How to get it for linux?

Comment: Hello @Noufal it was made in linux, as you can see in the directory structure /home/jgonzalez/

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I downloaded Cordova version from https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/, not from PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

If there is ANOTHER project loaded with your Phonegap project into Eclipse, then try to "Project >> Build All" on this project called "Something-CordovaLib" and after that "Project >> Clean..." your Phonegap application. This worked for me. Then the .jar file is magically created (or the dependency is somehow resolved)

Answer (score -2):

You have downloaded your package from the [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/). You should download it from [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/download/#) instead.

When you extract phonegap-2.7.0.zip, the jar and js files are located in:

```
phonegap-2.7.0\lib\android\
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I can't find it in my package, which is very different. Where did you download yours? It is not present either in the package available from Phonegap...

Comment: I see. You have to download it from phonegap.com instead of apache.org. I downloaded it from this link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/phonegap.download/phonegap-2.7.0.zip