# Unable to make a Cordova WebView on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm following the instructions [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews) to setup an Android WebView but I cannot get past step #2 below:

> 2. Navigate to the Android package's /framework directory and run ant
>      jar. It creates the Cordova .jar file, formed as
>      /framework/cordova-x.x.x.jar.

Running ant returns an error:

```
build.xml:42: You need to create the file 'local.properties' by running 'android update project -p .' here.
```

How can I get past this problem?

Comment: build.xml:42: You need to create the file 'local.properties' by running 'android update project -p .' here.

Answer (score 5):

1. You will have to choose the version of android you want to use, if you have downloaded the Android SDK and added to the path variable of your system you can do this:

   ```
   android list targets
   ```

   It will give you an answer like this one:

   ```
   Available Android targets:
   ----------
   id: 1 or "android-8"
   Name: Android 2.2
   Type: Platform
   API level: 8
   Revision: 3
   Skins: WQVGA432, QVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
   ABIs : armeabi
   ----------
   id: 2 or "android-17"
   Name: Android 4.2.2
   Type: Platform
   API level: 17
   Revision: 2
   Skins: WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA432, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
   ABIs : armeabi-v7a, x86
   ----------
   id: 3 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
   Name: Google APIs
   Type: Add-On
   Vendor: Google Inc.
   Revision: 3
   Description: Android + Google APIs
   Based on Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
   Libraries:
   * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
     Collection of video effects
   * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
     API for USB Accessories
   * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
     API for Google Maps
   Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
   ABIs : armeabi-v7a
   ----------
   id: 4 or "android-19"
   Name: Android 4.4
   Type: Platform
   API level: 19
   Revision: 1
   Skins: WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA432, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
   ABIs : armeabi-v7a
   ```
2. I choose the highest one i have so I did:

   ```
   android update project -p . -t android-19
   ```
3. And finally

   ```
   ant jar
   ```

   The result is something like:

   ```
   jar:
   [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Daniele\Desktop\cordova-android\framework\cor
   dova-3.5.1.jar

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   Total time: 11 seconds
   ```

Now you've got your jar.
(A more detailed explanation can be found at [Where is cordova-2.7.0.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199665/3138238))

Answer (score 0):

follow the instruction, run 'android update project -p .'

Comment: although it is useful. looks isnt exact answer. Please explain more.