# Making a CordovaWebView on Android, stuck on first step: Where is the Cordova distribution needed to build cordova-x.x.x.jar?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to build `cordova-x.x.x.jar` so that I can embed a Cordova-enabled WebView into my Android app. According to [these instructions](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html), the first step is to download the Cordova package:

> 1. To follow these instructions, make sure you have the latest Cordova
>      distribution. Download it from cordova.apache.org and unzip its
>      Android package.
> 2. Navigate to the Android package's /framework directory and run `ant jar`. It creates the Cordova .jar file, formed as /framework/cordova-x.x.x.jar.

Cordova however, has been living on NPM [since 2015](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), so there's no Cordova package to download.

Where do I find the /framework directory? Do I need to download Cordova a second time, or is it located within my NPM repository somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub currently (as of 6/2016) mirrors the cordova-android project [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/releases). You'll still need to download and install [ant](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), and pick a version of Android to build for (see StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718664/unable-to-make-a-cordova-webview-on-android)).

**Also**: If you want a WebView with JavaScript enabled, pure WebView can do that too. So you might want to start there first. :)